# How do I remove the last border on my nav bar?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have a website, the nav bar currently looks like

Home | News | About Us |

How do I remove the line after "About Us"?

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a href="index.php">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="news.php">NEWS</a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    width:40%;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-right:8%;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Microsoft Yi Baiti;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: black;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    color: rgb(204,204,204);
}


nav li.last {
    border: none ;
}
```

The last line in CSS I attempted to remove the border, but it unfortunately does not work. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:last-child` pseudo class on your `li` and target the anchor tags.

Like so:

```
nav ul li:last-child a{
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the border on the `a` tag not the `li`. Also `li` does not have a class of `last` so use `:last-child`. You want to target it like this:

```
nav li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqe9hc6y/